# How to call async function one by one in the initState function with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Assume that I would like get the data from the backend server, and I called the API by post method at the initState. I would like to call the following function one by one.

```
Map response = {};
Map response2 = {};

void initState() {
   callAPI_1();
   callAPI_2();
   ShowData();
}

void callAPI_1() async {
   .
   .
   .
   HttpClientResponse responseBody = await request.close();

   this.setState((){
      response = responseBody;
   });
}


void callAPI_2() async {
   .
   .
   .
   HttpClientResponse responseBody2 = await request2.close();

   this.setState((){
      response2 = responseBody2;
   });
}

void ShowData() {
   print(response);
   print(response2);
}
```

Expecting the order of the programming flow should be initState -> callAPI_1 ->  callAPI_1  -> ShowData;

Any suggestion of how to achieve it?

Comment: Create another async function and call it from initState, something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Map response = {};
Map response2 = {};

void initState() {
   asyncMethod();
   
}
asyncMethod() async{
await callAPI_1();
await callAPI_2();
await  ShowData();


void callAPI_1() async {
   .
   .
   .
   HttpClientResponse responseBody = await request.close();

   this.setState((){
      response = responseBody;
   });
}


void callAPI_2() async {
   .
   .
   .
   HttpClientResponse responseBody2 = await request2.close();

   this.setState((){
      response2 = responseBody2;
   });
}

void ShowData() {
   print(response);
   print(response2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`

like

```
@override
  void initState() {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await callAPI_1();
      await callAPI_2();
      ShowData();
    });
  }
```